# bash 3.2 regex pattern not matched while using =~

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to match a simple regex in a bash script. It behaves as expected with **GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)** but does not with **GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)**

here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

line="[foo]"
[[ $line =~ ^\[.*\]$ ]] && echo "regex matched"
echo "value of \$? : " $?
echo "value of BASH_REMATCH : " $BASH_REMATCH
/bin/bash --version|grep "GNU bash"
```

here is the output with **GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)**

> regex matched
> value of $? :  0
> value of BASH_REMATCH :  [foo]
> GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

here is the output with **GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)**

> value of $? :  1
> value of BASH_REMATCH : 
> GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

I've read a lot of post here and elsewhere regarding the behaviors of the oparator in **=~** and I can't find anyone who haves the same problem. I saw that there were major changes in bash 3.2 but as far as I see it should work from 3.2 onward.

Comment: Please take note that I've already tried to include it in a case statement, as in: "case $line in ^\[.*\]$ )"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some form of escaping problem.

This works here (bash version `3.2.25(1)-release`):

```
line="[foo]"
bar="^\[.*\]$"
[[ $line =~ $bar ]] && echo "regex matched"
```

This also appears to work:

```
[[ $line =~ ^\\[.*\\]$ ]] && echo "regex matched"
```

Comment: All right @Mat. Your first solution is working on both versions. I must say that I tried doing: `[[ $line =~ "^\[.*\]$" ]]` before posting but it was not behaving as expected. Doing `bar="^\[.*\]$"` then `[[ $line =~ $bar ]]` works. Do you know what's the difference between these 2 ways of wrinting?

Comment: Your second solution does not work in `GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)`. Merci ;)

Comment: I don't really know why what you had didn't work, or, for that matter, why the double-escaped one does (in 3.2). Might be a bug. See this [bash FAQ](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ) item E14 for some info related to bash versions and that `[[ =~ ]]` thing. The "stuff it in a variable" trick works well enough.